# Ajax post render partial unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial

JS POST

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ModifyTeam/ModifyTeam",
    data: teamName,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Textstatus: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

MVC COntroller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ModifyTeam(string teamName)
    {
        var user = Context.Users.FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString()));

        foreach (Team team in user.teams)
        {
            if (team.TeamName == teamName)
            {
                return PartialView(team);
            }
        }
        return PartialView();
    }
```

VIEW

```
      @model SportsFantasy_2._0.Models.Team
 <div>
<p>
    HEJAAANS!!
</p>
  </div>
```

Half way through rendering the partial view it stops and the ajaxpost goes to error: and writes out Textstatus: parsererror errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
What is the problem? There is no unexpected token here?:S

Comment: there is no closing div though?

Comment: Sorry i missed the tag but it is there!:)

Answer (score 2):

```
dataType: "json",
```

You just told jQuery to parse the response as JSON.

Since your HTML is not valid JSON, you're going to get an error.

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: Just remove that line to get the raw response body.

Comment: It still doesn't render the view it just sends back "<h2>hej</h2>
<form>
    <p>Spelarna</p>
</form>
" to the ajax-post

Comment: @DanielGustafsson: You need to do something with the response.

Comment: Then you probably want to put the HTML into the DOM.

Comment: Look at the `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your datatype in the ajax call.

```
dataType: "json"
```

to

```
dataType: "html",
```

Your expected datatype json, but you send back the partial view which is html. So, parsing html to json data throws the error.

datatype - type of data you want back from the server.